# How do you know the version of the remote mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

How do you know the version of the remote mercurial repository ?

the remote repository i want to check version is accessible only via http protocol.

the question is use correct client version of Mersurial. and also to know what is supported by server. For example after version 1.8 bookmarks ability were added to the core and i want to know do i can use them with repository installed on the remote part.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply try to do whatever it is you're trying to do. The wire protocol is forward-compatible: the client asks the server what are its capabilities, so it knows what the server can do.

If the destination doesn't support pulling/pushing bookmarks (which is the `pushkey` mechanism), pushing a bookmark will simply fail.

As for using the correct client version, not sure what that means. If you mean accessing a local repository with the "matching" version, that's usually not a problem since repository layout changes are not very frequent.

In the case where things have changed, Mercurial is kind enough to tell you that your version can't read this repository (this is what the [`.hg/requires`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RequiresFile) file is for):

> abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a process listening for your request (like [ssh for instance](http://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/using_mercurial_with_ssh), allowing you to `ssh server-host hg version`, but you have http only), a remote repo won't give you that information.

`hg version` works locally, and I don't think any [`hgweb.cgi`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryHowTo%5Cb%29) would interpret that request, since those cgi are about publishing the repo (data), not about publishing information about the tool (meta-data) managing the repo on the remote server.